# A question about plane convex sets

Tags: general-topology

Let E(2) be the Euclidean Plane with its standard topology. Let C(2) be a compact convex subset of E(2) whose boundary (with respect to) E(2) is non-empty. Is the boundary of C(2) (with respect to) E(2) always a Jordan curve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $C_2=\{{\bf 0}\}$ or $C_2=\{(t,0)\,|\,0\leq t\leq 1\}$ then $\partial C_2=C_2$ is not a Jordan curve. It is another matter if $C_2$ has nonempty interior. If ${\bf 0}\in{\rm int}(C_2)$ then it should be possible to produce a bijective representation $\phi\mapsto {\bf z}(\phi)$ of $\partial C_2$ where $\phi$ denotes the polar angle of ${\bf z}(\phi)$.

Comment: Thanks for this response. There is a booboo in my question. I meant to stipulate that the interior -and not the boundary-of C(2) is non-empty.. This means that the answer to my question is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

As Christian Blatter demonstrated, you have to assume that $\mathrm{int}(C_2)\not=\varnothing$. So assume $0\in\mathrm{int}(C_2)$. Then, for any $v\in S^1$ the ray $\{\alpha v\mid \alpha> 0\}$ intersects $\partial C_2$ at most once.

*Proof.*

Because $0$ is an interior point, we have a small ball $B_0(\epsilon)\subset C_2$. Assume there are two intersections $\alpha v,\alpha'v\in\partial C_2$ with $\alpha'<\alpha$. Because of convexity we have $B_{t v}((\alpha-t)\epsilon)\subset C_2,t\in[0,\alpha]$ (you move the ball over to $\alpha v$ be shrinking it linearly). But then, for $t=\alpha'$ we have $B_{\alpha' v}(\alpha-\alpha')$ as a neighborhood of $\alpha'v$ in $C_2$, so $\alpha' v$ cannot be a boundary point. Contradiction. $\;\square$

So this gives us an injective map $S^1\to\partial C_2$. We also show surjectivity (i.e. the ray intersects at least once):

*Proof.*

For any $v\in S^1$ there exists $\alpha=\sup \{\alpha'\mid \alpha' v\in C_2\}<\infty$ (because $C_2$ is bounded). Because $C_2$ is closed we have $\alpha v\in C_2$, which then is necessarily a boundary point. $\;\square$

This implies that we have a bijection $\varphi:S^1\leftrightarrow \partial C_2$. It remains to show that it is continuous. The map $\varphi^{-1}:\partial C_2\to S^1$ is given by $x\mapsto x/\|x\|$ and is obviously continuous because $0\notin \partial C_2$. It remains to show this for the inverse. Maybe I will add this part later. For now I have no nice short proof, but it might be not very hard.

As soon as you have shown that this $\varphi$ is a continuous bijection between $S^1$ and $\partial C_2$ you are done. $\partial C_2$ is a Jordan curve.